# Paypal API - Clients to accept payments with paypal from theirs clients

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am working in a application that helps companies manage their finances.
They can create invoice for clients, send with email to clients and now we wanted to implement the Paypal to let clients pay them through our platform.

While looking at the Paypay API's I can not figure out which is the best to be used in this case. 
I am referring to the two options:

- REST API
- Classic API

Can anyone please recommend me which on of the options is the best one to be used in our case to enable our clients to receive payments in our platform?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check [here](https://developer.paypal.com/). As it says if you want to add subscription kind of payment you need to use classic otherwise use REST API for simple payment options

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the Classic API.  It's much more mature than the REST API, so it has more features that REST just doesn't have yet.  They keep developing on it, too, so it's tough to say when REST might (if ever) catch up with it.

With a decent SDK the classic API is no more difficult than REST to implement.  If you happen to be using PHP I'd recommend taking a look at my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/).  It will make all of the Classic API calls very simple for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. Can I ask you which function I need to use to get authorization of company to receive payments with paypal?

Comment: If you're just talking about allowing people to pay invoices then you could use the Invoicing API (CreateInvoice, CreateAndSendInvoice, etc.) to generate PayPal invoices that would be manageable through the PayPal interface for both buyer and seller.  Alternatively, you could setup your own invoice payment system and use the Express Checkout API to process payments through that.  That would involve SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails, and DoExpressCheckoutPayment.